# Boolean SOP Expression Simplification: $F(a,b,c,d) = (a+d)(a'b+c'd)(ac+bd)'$

Tags: boolean-algebra

my answer that I have gotten is $b'c'd + a' b d'$
however, the answer given to me was b'c'd
can someone tell me whether I am correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I calculated, the correct answer is b'c'd

Could you show the steps you used?

Comment: (a+d)(a′b+c′d)(ac+bd)′ = (aa'b+ac'd+a'bd+c'd)(a'+c')(b'+d')

Comment: Yes, aa'b = 0
The product will be (a'bd+c'd)(b'+d') which will lead you to b'c'd

Comment: managed to work it out, was careless! any tips on simplification since i am doing it by expanding all the terms once at a time

Comment: When you expand (ac'd+a'bd+c'd)(a'+c'), four of the six terms will cancel out.

Answer (score 0):

1530261   
$F\equiv((a\lor d)\land((\lnot a\land b)\lor(\lnot c\land d))\land\lnot((a\land c)\lor(b\land d)))$

$\begin{array}
ee\equiv(a\lor d)\\
f\equiv(\lnot a)\\
g\equiv(f\land b)\\
h\equiv(\lnot c)\\
i\equiv(h\land d)\\
j\equiv(g\lor i)\\
k\equiv(e\land j)\\
l\equiv(a\land c)\\
m\equiv(b\land d)\\
n\equiv(l\lor m)\\
o\equiv(\lnot n)\\
\hline
F\equiv(k\land o)
\end{array}$

$\begin{array}{cccc|ccccccccccc|c}
a&b&c&d&e&f&g&h&i&j&k&l&m&n&o&F\\
\hline
0&0&0&0&0&1&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1&1&1&0&1&1&1&1&0&0&0&1&1\\
0&0&1&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&1&1&1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0\\
0&1&0&0&0&1&1&1&0&1&0&0&0&0&1&0\\
0&1&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&0&1&1&0&0\\
0&1&1&0&0&1&1&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&1&0\\
0&1&1&1&1&1&1&0&0&1&1&0&1&1&0&0\\
1&0&0&0&1&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0\\
1&0&0&1&1&0&0&1&1&1&1&0&0&0&1&1\\
1&0&1&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&1&0&0\\
1&0&1&1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&1&0&0\\
1&1&0&0&1&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0\\
1&1&0&1&1&0&0&1&1&1&1&0&1&1&0&0\\
1&1&1&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&1&0&0\\
1&1&1&1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&0&0
\end{array}$

This is a step-by-step truth table of your logical function. As you can see, somewhere in your parsing you came up with an extra term.